# How to set GIF as a background in Linear?

Tags: java, background, gif

How to set GIF as a Linear in linear in Android Studio? Method with glide didn't help. What to do?

Comment: Please demonstrate explicitly (code snippet) of your attempt to solve a problem yourself

Comment: Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.gif).into(new SimpleTarget<Drawable>() {
   @Override
   public void onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Transition<? super Drawable> transition) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
     linear2.setBackground(resource);
    }
   }
  });

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Request Listner in Glide.

Use below code for Kotlin:

```
 Glide.with(context).load(imageUrl)
        .apply(RequestOptions().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL))
        .listener(object : RequestListener<Drawable> {
            override fun onLoadFailed(
                e: GlideException?,
                model: Any?, target: com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target<Drawable>?,
                isFirstResource: Boolean
            ): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun onResourceReady(
                resource: Drawable?,model: Any?,
                target: com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target<Drawable>?,
                dataSource: DataSource?, isFirstResource: Boolean
            ): Boolean {
                view.setBackground(resource)
                return true
            }
        })
        .into(view)
```

For Java:

```
Glide.with(this).load("imageUrl")
            .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    view.setBackground(resource);
                    return false;
                }
            }).into(view);
```

Comment: It's give error in: .into(linear2);
cannot resolve method '.into(android.widget.LinearLayout)'
Java

Comment: you can put any ImageView and hide the visibility of that ImageView.